# Link to Google Maps with a Label

Tags: google-maps

I have a webapp where I have geolocated business, there's a section where the coordinates are shown and when you click on them you should be redirected to Google Maps with the name of the business on the marker.

This was an easy task with the old Google Maps application but currently the old method

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&q=42.3,-8.53+(Business name)&ll=42.3,-8.53
```

does not work anymore.

How can I do this with the newest Google Maps?

Comment: As far as I can see, the link provided goes to a google maps v3 page.

Comment: It does, but it does not show the label, which is what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: You can't do that anymore. This used to work but doesn't work anymore. Unable to find more information about why and when they changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it doesn’t work on the new version of Google maps. You'll have to append:

```
&output=classic
```

to your link.